# How to extract values of a property inside an array of objects- JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like:

```js
const array = [
    { id: "LAX" },
    { id: "BAS" },
    { id: "TES" },
    { id: "LAX" },
    { id: "LAX" },
    { id: "ATL" },
    { id: "BNA" },
    { id: "LAX" },
  ];
```

Here I'm trying to remove duplicate values of `id` using `Set`

```
[...new Set(array)]
```

is not currently helping.

I'm basically trying to achieve a result like below:

```
["LAX", "BAS", "TES"....] // with no duplicates.
```

Any es6 reasons for this?

Comment: you're looking for `new Set(array.map(x => x.id))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: and [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before using Set to create your data, you should map your data based on a key. this will solve your problem:

```
const array =[
  {id: "LAX"},
  {id: "BAS"},
  {id: "TES"},
  {id: "LAX"},
  {id: "LAX"},
  {id: "ATL"},
  {id: "BNA"},
  {id: "LAX"}]
const result = [...new Set(array.map(item => item.id))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this snippet of code will solve your problem.

```js
const array = [
  { id: "LAX" },
  { id: "BAS" },
  { id: "TES" },
  { id: "LAX" },
  { id: "LAX" },
  { id: "ATL" },
  { id: "BNA" },
  { id: "LAX" },
];
const myset = new Set();
array.forEach((value) => myset.add(value.id));
const newArr = Array.from(myset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [{
    id: "LAX"
  },
  {
    id: "BAS"
  },
  {
    id: "TES"
  },
  {
    id: "LAX"
  },
  {
    id: "LAX"
  },
  {
    id: "ATL"
  },
  {
    id: "BNA"
  },
  {
    id: "LAX"
  }
];
const unique = [...new Map(array.map((m) => [m.id, m])).values()];
console.log(unique)
```